# numpy : how to multiply two arrays of matrix

Tags: numpy

Say a.shape is (2, 3, 1), b.shape is (2, 1, 4). They both represent an array of matrix, how to element-wise multiply those two arrays of matrix so that the result's shape is (2, 3, 4).

Comment: yes, matrix multiplication

Comment: I mean just multiply `array1 * array2`, as the broadcasting would give us the desired o/p of (2,3,4) shape.

Comment: It works, can't believe it's that simple, thanks.

Comment: @Blake, you seem to be confused about elementwise vs matrix multiplication. In this case, they happen to be the same, because `a` is a column vector and `b` a row vector. But if you want this to work for other values, you should be using `@` (np.matmul)